# Issue in running Spring Restful web services without Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I am trying to build Restful web services. My Maven project name is ***rest*** and I am following [Spring's Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)  to do that but I don't want to use Spring Boot but just create a war and host it on Tomcat in my eclise/STS. Here are my web.xml and XX-servlet.xml files:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**rest-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.rest" />
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>


</beans>
```

**GreetingController.java**

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController2 {
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format("Hello %s", name));
    }
}
```

when I run this on Tomcat the URL: http://localhost:8080/rest gives 404 and I see this message in tomcat console `Aug 16, 2017 3:59:28 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
 WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rest/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'`
 whereas I do have the mapping.

And when I hit http://localhost:8080/rest/greeting I get http 406 with message `The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.` whereas as per the tutorial it should be converted to JSON which can be rendered in the browser.

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out and looking at various posts on SO to find what's wrong but could not.

Comment: Akshay Srivastava's answer helped me find the issue. In addition to what he mentioned, I did not have Jackson JSON dependencies which is why it was not able to convert my object to JSON. When I added those to my pom.xml I could see http://localhost:8080/rest/greeting  working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont have a default mapping like
@RequestMapping("/")
As per your code above you should have below url working fine
 http://localhost:8080/rest/greeting

Comment: I get http 406 with message `The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.` for http://localhost:8080/rest/greeting

Comment: add all the jackson jar dependencies and if already added then add accept header as applciation/json. If you are using chrome then prefer using postman rest client and change the accept header to application/json. Jackson dependencies include jackson-core, jackson-databing, jackson-annotations

Comment: I see, when I return a String from my method it does render it. So yes it's with converting the object to JSON that's not working. I will try what you suggested. Thanks Akshay +1

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: what change do I need to make to have http://localhost:8080 and http://localhost:8080/rest/  show some relevant page?

Comment: You are using rest and not mvc controller that would return your view from controller. As of now you could create an HTML and make a rest call to your api. For mapping localhost:8080/rest just create another method with request mapping as @RequestMapping("/")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152101/discussion-between-akshay-srivastava-and-learner).